# Запятая и тире как единый знак при выделении вставной конструкции

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, вставная-конструкция

В современном тексте пришлось столкнуться с предложением: *Ребенок изучает других через себя, – это путь эмоций и впечатлений.*

- Вот что написано в правиле: *Примечание 2. При оформлении вставных конструкций в середине предложения встречается употребление запятой и тире как единого знака препинания: Вы садитесь в коляску, – это так приятно после вагона , – и катите по степной дороге (Ч.). Такое выделение для современных текстов не характерно.* (https://orfogrammka.ru)
- Допустим, не характерно, но встречается. Можно ли оставить запятую, опираясь на это примечание? Возможно, есть другие формулировки насчет запятой и тире как единого знака при выделении вставных конструкций, более либеральные (разумеется, у авторитетных авторов)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Работаем по правилам Розенталя или ПАС**, этих авторитетов достаточно, а других нет (остальные авторы ориентируются на их правила).

1) **Вы садитесь в коляску – это так приятно после вагона  – и катите по степной дороге** (Ч.).

Запятая и тире как единый знак (по Розенталю) **не относятся к теме вставных конструкций.** Вставные конструкции выделяются тире, а дополнительные запятые ставятся по соответствующим правилам и зависят от знаков на месте вставки (эти правила есть у Розенталя).

http://feb-web.ru/feb/chekhov/texts/sp0/sp9/sp9-313-.htm

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=123#pp123

1) с обеих сторон ставится только тире, если в месте вставки дополнительных сведений **не должно быть никакого знака препинания:** Аннушка молча покинула свою засаду, тихо обошла кругом — её детские ножки едва шумели по густой траве — и вышла из чащи подле самого старика (Т.);

2) **Ребенок изучает других через себя, – это путь эмоций и впечатлений.**

Это БСП, информация по выбору знака также есть у Розенталя

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=152#pp152

1. Запятая и тире часто ставятся в бессоюзном сложном предложении перед словом это или вот, начинающим присоединительное предложение: Эдгар По считается отличным мастером формы, оригинальным художником, — это бесспорно (М. Г.);

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=151#pp151 **(тире или запятая и тире)**

8. Тире ставится перед местоименными словами так, такой, таков, начинающими собой присоединительное предложение, входящее в состав бессоюзного сложного предложения: Приказ есть приказ — так его воспитал фронт (Вор.); Кривые улицы, маленькие деревянные дома — такой была значительная часть Москвы в начале XX века. Идти вперёд или погибнуть — таков был выбор у партизанского отряда;
   В этих предложениях выражены **суждения, субъект которых назван в первой части, а предикат образует вторую часть.** Если логические отношения между обеими частями носят другой характер, то между ними ставятся **запятая и тире**: Загрязнение окружающей среды угрожает жизни на Земле, — так дальше продолжаться не может (Газ.). [См. § 46, п. 2.]